# FrameLayout textview over image disappear after i set the programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-framelayout

I have a recyclerview item that is a frameLayout with an ImageView and a TextView over it.
I have set the xml values but inside the onBindViewHolder i do some actions and set the values to the views

The layout is like bleow

```
<FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/img_frame"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/message_received_item"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <com.package.views.RoundedImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_rcv_msg_image"
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="210dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:elevation="8dp"
                android:maxWidth="320dp"
                android:maxHeight="320dp"
                android:minWidth="150dp"
                android:minHeight="150dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:bottomRightCorner="20dp"
                app:topLeftCorner="20dp"
                app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_report_image"
                tools:ignore="ContentDescription" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_rcvName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top|start"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="Unknown"
                android:textColor="#f00"
                android:textSize="12sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/img_rcv_msg_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:text="--:--"
                android:textColor="#f00"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />

        </FrameLayout>
```

At the layout Design preview of the Android Studio i can correctly see the TextViews ABOVE the ImageView (which is custom but no worries). However in the onBind of the RecyclerView i calculate my values and when i set the Bitmap to the ImageView and the text to the TextViews the TextViews are not shown at all. I suppose the hide behind the ImageView.
Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first assumption is that your RoundedImageView is above the text (due to the elevation attribute). Remove elevation from ImageView or set TextView to greater than 8